# Is there an update for php 8.2 repository for Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: php, repository, 22.10

Trying to add `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` but there is a problem. I am using Kubuntu 22.10. Any thoughts if this can be done? I would like to use php 8.2

```
Ign:14 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu kinetic InRelease                
Err:15 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu kinetic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done                              

E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a brief look at all of those PPAs, and none of them have builds for 22.10. You're really best off contacting the maintainer of the PPA - [https://launchpad.net/~ondrej](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej)

They'll be able to explain their plans.

Comment: Ondřej said he will only support Ubuntu LTS, so no 22.10. https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1662